# Populate a hierarchical select field programmatically

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have to create a user, and one of the fields (**Profession**) is a hierarchical select based on a two level taxonomy, where the **first level is "profession"**, and **each profession has different specialities**.

I can create a user and save the profession field, but the speciality is not saved, and that's what I want to do. Here is how I save the profession :

```
$fields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'mail' => $email,
    'pass' => $password,
    ...
    'field_profession' => array('und' => array(array('tid' => $tid_profession))),
);
user_save('', $fields);
```

Here, `$tid_profession` is the id of the profession term. However, when I use the id of the speciality term, the field is not saved.

Any idea how to make this work ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have saved user with custom hirerarical select field named "field_register_state" like below: it's working very well.

```
$account = new stdClass;
$account->is_new = TRUE;
$account->name = $username;
$account->pass = user_hash_password($form_state['values']['pass']);
$account->mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];
$account->init = $form_state['values']['mail'];
$account->status = TRUE;

$account->field_user_code = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value'=>$userCode)));
$account->field_full_name = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value'=>$form_state['values']['field_full_name']['und'][0]['value'])));
$account->roles = array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',$form_state['values']['roles']=>getRoleNameById($form_state['values']['roles'],$form));

$account->field_user_area_name = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value'=>$areaName)));
$account->field_created_by = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value'=>0)));
$account->field_register_state = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('tid'=>$statecode)));
$account->timezone = variable_get('date_default_timezone'); 
user_save($account);
drupal_set_message(t('User Created Successfully'), 'status');
```

Hope this help's you..

Comment: Thanks, indeed, your code, like mine is valid, but I found out it was the configuration of the widget of my field which caused the problem, like I explain in my answer. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was not in the code, which works fine, but in the configuration of the field.

Instead of saving all the lineage, I had to save only the deepest term, and then, both my child and parent fields were correctly saved.

Answer (score 0):

The following may not work for you but it did turn out to be the right approach on my end. Thanks Kamal!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function custom_module_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $tid = 10;
  $account = user_load($account->uid);
  $account->field_location_map = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('tid'=> $tid)));
  user_save($account);
}
```